# Spring Boot: does @Entity Annotation exist?

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-boot

I watched this Spring Boot tutorial: https://javabrains.io/courses/spring_bootquickstart/lessons/Creating-a-Spring-Data-JPA-Repository

and it puts an @Entity annotation before a class name. When I tried to do it in my code, I got an Error saying "can't resolve @Entity".

Here is my pom.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/><!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>


    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.persistence</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
            <artifactId>derby</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Do you know what is the problem?

Comment: Have you included all the libraries for Spring and persistence API?

Comment: Yes. I edited the original post. You can see all the dependencies.

Comment: it’s pulled in transitively via spring-boot-starter-data-jpa

Comment: Possible duplicate of [javax.persistence.Entity doesn't exist](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43833662/javax-persistence-entity-doesnt-exist)

Comment: For MAVEN Update Issues Please check this 
 : https://stackoverflow.com/a/75246439/81511

Answer (score 19):

I also faced this problem recently. For me, the `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` dependency was the issue. Although it was in the `pom.xml` file without any errors, but the jars were not there in classpath - even after syncing maven and importing dependencies multiple times in different ways ( mvn clean/update/install).

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

The IDE I was using was IntelliJ Idea.

What worked for me at last : I just put this dependency over all other dependencies inside the `<dependencies>` ... `</dependencies>` tag, i.e just changed the order of dependencies and synced. That worked in my case, not sure why.

Below is my `pom.xml` file contents for reference.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>dev.sanskar.courses</groupId>
<artifactId>course-api</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>


    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    </dependency>


    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.persistence/javax.persistence-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.persistence-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-validator -->
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate.javax.persistence/hibernate-jpa-2.1-api -->
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate.javax.persistence/hibernate-jpa-2.1-api -->
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.persistence/persistence-api -->


</dependencies>

<properties> 
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>


<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Can someone explain why this works? This worked for me too. But I would like to understand the underlying issue and the reason for this fix working.

Answer (score 11):

**Use spring-boot-starter-data-jpa**

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId> 
</dependency>
```

It works for me ... :)

**Do not use the following one**

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
 </dependency>
```

Comment: why not use the other one ?

Answer (score 4):

I added this dependency

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.persistence-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

Add this and enjoy.

Answer (score 2):

Spring STS usually shows this error when the set up isn't correct.

1. Go to the line containing the error
2. Click on the alert bulb so that it can suggest possible fixes
3. From the options, choose the "Fix project setup"

Follow the rest so that the project then re-aligns the import order.

Answer (score 1):

suppose you have missed a dependency.

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

There are useful sample spring boot projects in this github [page](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-data-jpa).it will be helpful to have a look.

Comment: But I didn't miss it. It's there

Comment: yes.suppose you are correct. try with adding maven plugin. Make sure you have `import javax.persistence.Entity`.

Comment: When I write 'import javax.persistence.Entity' I get an error: 'Can't resolve Entity'. Probably, my IDE doesn't recognize Entity inside javax.persistence.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, by adding the spring-boot-starter-data-jpa dependency to the classpath it worked.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. After I configured the new dependency on `pom.xml` file, the `@Entity` annotation is not found because these dependencies is not found. To solve it, the `IntelliJ IDE` then suggested me to load the Maven changes. On the `pom.xml` screen, click on the icon to reload Maven.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the answers here are *hit and try types* which doesn't explain why @Entity annotation was not working and why it started working after adding certain dependencies.

**Here's how it works-**

For using persistence annotations you need to add relevant dependencies with their version, let's say we add ***spring-boot-starter-data-jpa*** as follows-

```
  <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
         <version>2.6.6</version>
      </dependency>
```

Now when you are using Intellij Idea as your IDE, you need to reload your maven project to re read the dependencies from your **pom.xml**.

Once you do that, @Entity annotation would be available for use.

Answer (score 1):

What Worked For Me In Last:-

1. Go To File -> Project Structure -> Modules -> Click On Your Project Name
2. Then Go To Dependencies click "+" and Then -> Library -> From Maven
3. Then Search For javax.persistence.api Then Click Ok And Apply Changes

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you Maven projects are imported successfully.

In the lower right corner of your IntelliJ there will a prompt asking you if you want to import the changes. It will also ask you if you want to enable Auto-Import.

Answer (score 0):

Do a force update `mvn clean install -U` or you can right click on `your project -->maven--> update` if you are using eclipse/STS. this synchronizes the IDE with pom dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are working with EclipseLink JPA implementation,

```
 <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.persistence</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Spring Data JPA works with **Hibernate** implementation by default. We need to exclude unnecessary Hibernate dependencies from `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa`when working with other JPA implementations.

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
```

If you are working with Hibernate, just `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` is enough in your case.

I also seen "can't resolve @Entity" issue because of my IDE. In eclipse, click Project option -> Clean the project. This is solved my issue when project dependencies out of sync with IDE.

Answer (score 0):

Click on the red bulb next to the @Entity annotation.
Choose "Add dependency" - choose "javax.persistence.api" (NOT jakarta)

Answer (score 0):

1. go to File -> Project Structure -> Project Settings -> Facets in Intellij Idea
2. click "+" and add "JPA" module

Answer (score 0):

i faced same issue, after add this dependencies fixed my issue

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.persistence-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issues recently and i resolved it using adding this dependency that given below. I think the version change in spring boot made this error, now  `javax.persistence` is not available instead we can use `jakarta.persistence`

```
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>6.1.6.Final</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

I added the javax.persistence in the pom.xml file as a dependency, but it still required the version, so I grabbed a version  from mvn repositories,  this is what my dependency looks  like, this was using eclipse editor. And it worked.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.persistence-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score -2):

put this in your file at the top as an import statement

```
import javax.persistence.*;
```