# Eclipse failure during a maven update

Tags: eclipse, maven, pom.xml, m2eclipse, uml-eclipse-plugin

First of all, probably my question is not well asked or is too easy or too simple but I'm a little bit novice and Vaadin and I can't figure what is happening.

When I try to update the maven project using "Update project" doing right client over "pom.xml", I get the following error over and over.

```
An internal error occurred during: "Updating Maven Project".
Receiver class com.baselet.plugin.MavenProjectChangedListener does not define or inherit an implementation of the resolved method 'abstract void mavenProjectChanged(java.util.List, org.eclipse.core.runtime.IProgressMonitor)' of interface org.eclipse.m2e.core.project.IMavenProjectChangedListener.
```

When I click "ok", the same error appears again and again.

I'm using:

- Eclipse 2022-12
- JDK Zulu 17
- Apache Maven 3.8.7 which I downloaded and I selected at Eclipse's configuration.

I tried several projects and it is always the same. Could someone give me an advise?

Regards,

Comment: Does it work with the embedded Maven?

Comment: Same error, that's why I tried to use a different Maven.

Comment: It seems you have the [_Bazel Eclipse Feature_](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/bazel-eclipse-feature) installed which seems not to work with the current m2e plugin. Which version is your _Bazel Eclipse Feature_? Is it up to date?

Comment: I took a look over my installation details and Bazel is not installed. For the record, my m2e plugin is in version 2.1.2.

Comment: Then what is `com.baselet.plugin` which must be something you have installed? See https://github.com/eclipse-m2e/m2e-core/issues/991

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The **current [UMLet plugin](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/umlet-uml-tool-fast-uml-diagrams)** which you have installed **does not work** with the current Eclipse Maven integration (m2e) 2.x of **Eclipse 2022-09 and higher** containing **m2e 2.x** in contrast to previous Eclipse IDE releases.

Please [make sure the issue has been reported to the UMLet project](https://github.com/umlet/umlet/issues).

See also [m2e issue #991](https://github.com/eclipse-m2e/m2e-core/issues/991), closed as not a m2e issue with the following [comment by Mickael Istria](https://github.com/eclipse-m2e/m2e-core/issues/991#issuecomment-1281856878):

> It looks like the com.baselet plugin is not compatible with m2e 2.x.
> Please report issue to that plugin

[For details see my comment here](https://github.com/eclipse-m2e/m2e-core/issues/991#issuecomment-1405027827).

Comment: Thanks! for the record, that is a problem which was solved but the real solution for my problem was uninstall the plugin UMLet which have some conflict situations.

Comment: @SamuelGóngora Thx for this information. I have updated the answer accordingly and added a comment to the m2e issue.